# How do I get data about a sent email from the FuelSDK (or otherwise)?

Tags: fuel-sdk, ruby

Calling [`FuelSDK::SentEvent.new`](https://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/fuel-sdks/tracking/sent-tracking.html) returns a `SendID`.

How do I use that to find information about the Email that was sent by this send event?  I don't see any equivalent client objects in FuelSDK-Ruby anywhere.

Specifically, I need to identify if I generated this specific Email via `FuelSDK::Email.new` earlier, or if it was a manually created email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by adding another class to the FuelSDK for the `Send` object.

Add this to `lib/fuelsdk/objects.rb` somewhere, like right before `class SentEvent`:

```
class Send < Objects::Base
    attr_accessor :get_since_last_batch
    include Objects::Soap::Read
end
```

Then in your code you can do normal FuelSDK read operations, like so:

```
send_et_endpoint = FuelSDK::Send.new
send_et_endpoint.authStub = @client
send_et_endpoint.filter = {'Property' => 'ID', 'SimpleOperator' => 'equals', 'Value' => et_send_id}
send_et_endpoint.props = ['Email.ID', 'SendDate', 'FromAddress', 'EmailName']
s_get = send_et_endpoint.get
```